# Using PCRE library in native node modules

Tags: c++, node.js, module, native, pcre

I'm trying to use the PCRE library in native C++ nodejs modules. 
I added `#include "pcre\pcrecpp.h"` in my cpp file, but I'm getting

```
e:\nativenode\pcre\pcrecpp.h(334): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
 'pcre.h': No such file or directory [E:\nativenode\build\wikiparser.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\nativenode
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.12
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

so I thought the `pcre.h` file is just missing, I went in the `PCRE` dir and renamed pcre.h.generic to pcre.h ( so the file now exists ), but I'm getting the same error.
My folder looks like this

[image]

How I can get it running? Do I need to link the lib somewhere or just including `pcrecpp.h` is enought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are missing the proper include path.

https://github.com/mscdex/node-pcre appears to add the `include_dirs` field to gyp so that the build system sees the include:

https://github.com/mscdex/node-pcre/blob/master/deps/libpcre/pcre.gyp#L3-L5

```
'include_dirs': [
  '.',
],
```

Comment: That library is available directly on npm (`pcre`)